# After how many bytes stack overflow occurs

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

Let buffer size is 4 bytes. We give input of 4, 5, 6, 7 ,... bytes one by one. After how many bytes stack based overflow will occur. Buffer size is 4 bytes did input of 4 bytes will cause stack based overflow. In both 32 bit and 64 bit system did stack based overflow will occur after same no of bytes passed to program assuming same buffer size in both 32 bit and 64 bit program?

Answer (score 1):

If your buffer is 4 bytes long, when you put a 5th byte into it (in practice this means you write the 5th byte after the buffer pointer) a buffer overflow occurs by definition.

32 vs. 64-bit only matters if your buffer is an array of multi-byte types (e.g. integer). In this case a 2 element integer array will have the size of 8 and 16 bytes respectively.